# Are there any disadvantages to putting all script tags at the end of the body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Of course, there's the issue of loading times. That's why putting javascript at the end of the HTML has always been recommended.

However, are there cases where this shouldn't be done? Are there any disadvantages to this method?

Comment: Putting JavaScript at the end of HTML is also recommended for scripts that access the DOM; you don't, and most of the time you *can't*, access elements before they exist / have-been-rendered.

Comment: Yes.!!!! You will get an err of element name with id 'x' didn't find...

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, although it is very connected to this topic, I don't think it is a duplicate as it doesn't answer the question `What are the disadvantages`, of course, other than the slower times. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

The mindset I have for this question is if there is any consequence for not following the "standard" other than slower loading times.

Comment: @MarkGabriel, of all the questions about the same issue at SO, I selected the one that seems to have been answered most thoroughly. Both advantages and disadvantages are covered, and if there is something to be added to this, the additions are best made to an existing question with good answers.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are only disadvantages in some fairly specialized cases. For example, if you're using JavaScript to load web fonts, you may want to get the necessary requests started ASAP. Adam Beres-Deak had a [post](http://bdadam.com/blog/loading-webfonts-with-high-performance.html) on this recently.

For run of the mill JavaScript code, though, there aren't any disadvantages.